# Is the following stronger Sobolev inequality true or not

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a compact subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $p<n,\frac{1}{p*}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{n} $. The usual Sobolev ineuqality says that
\begin{equation}
\|u\|_{p*}\leq C (\|u\|_p+\|\nabla u\|_p)
\end{equation}
for $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. My question is, does the following stronger inequality holds:
\begin{equation}
\|u\|_{p*}\leq C (\|u\|^{\theta}_p\|\nabla u\|^{1-\theta}_p)
\end{equation}
where $0<\theta<1$.

Thanks for anyone who could help.

Comment: No. Take $u\equiv 1$ in $\Omega$ for example.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct.